# String to Object with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, object

I would like to know the most efficient way to convert this string into an object in JavaScript.

This is the ugly string:

```
  "\"date\",\"initRegistrations\",\"registrations\",\"finalizeRegistrations\"\r\n\"03/29/2017\",\"0\",\"0\",\"0\"\r\n\"03/30/2017\",\"5\",\"4\",\"4\"\r\n\"03/31/2017\",\"42\",\"0\",\"0\"\r\n\"04/01/2017\",\"192\",\"0\",\"0\"\r\n\"04/02/2017\",\"4\",\"0\",\"0\"\r\n\"04/03/2017\",\"23\",\"0\",\"0\"\r\n\"04/04/2017\",\"5\",\"0\",\"0\"\r\n"
```

At the moment I'm using this function, but it does not work fine, the expected output would be a object of object with the keys date, initRegistrations, registrations, finalizeRegistrations:

```
   function convertToArrayOfObjects(data) {
    var keys = data.shift(),
        i = 0, k = 0,
        obj = null,
        output = [];

    for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        obj = {};

        for (k = 0; k < keys.length; k++) {
          if(data[i][k]){
            obj[keys[k]] = data[i][k];
          }

        }

        output.push(obj);
    }

    return output;
}
```

Is there any fancy way to achieve this easily or I should go playing with my array of objects?
Any help or advice is appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: Is your "ugly string" the literal contents of the string or a string literal?

Comment: What is your expected output for that string?

Comment: "does not work fine" and how is it supposed to work? What's the intended vs achieved output?

Comment: @Triptych the expected output is a object of object with the keys date, initRegistrations, registrations, finalizeRegistrations.

Comment: @Victor I think you mean an array of objects? If so, please update your question with exact wording.

Comment: @Triptych Now I have an array of object full of quotes :(

Comment: Where did this data come from? It looks like CSV, or CSV with all of the double-quotes and line endings escaped a la JSON. It's a lot easier to decode something if you know how it was encoded.

Comment: @Jordan is just an API response

Comment: @Victor That doesn't tell us anything about the format of the data. APIs have documentation. What does this API's documentation tell you about how this data should be decoded?

Comment: You specified the input, now please specify the desired output

Comment: @Jordan if it were in the documentation I won't be asking here, I believe that is pretty obvious.

Comment: maybe an array of arrays? `var arrArr = s.split('\r\n').map(x => x.split(','))`

Comment: @naioman thanks for the help, is not working, the keys must be date, initRegistrations, registrations, finalizeRegistrations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably too functional for some, but this is how I'd write it.

```js
const s =   "\"date\",\"initRegistrations\",\"registrations\",\"finalizeRegistrations\"\r\n\"03/29/2017\",\"0\",\"0\",\"0\"\r\n\"03/30/2017\",\"5\",\"4\",\"4\"\r\n\"03/31/2017\",\"42\",\"0\",\"0\"\r\n\"04/01/2017\",\"192\",\"0\",\"0\"\r\n\"04/02/2017\",\"4\",\"0\",\"0\"\r\n\"04/03/2017\",\"23\",\"0\",\"0\"\r\n\"04/04/2017\",\"5\",\"0\",\"0\"\r\n";

// Remove surrounding quotes from a string.
const removeQuotes = s => s.replace(/^"|"$/g, '');

// Split input by newline ('\r\n')
const lines = s.trim().split('\r\n');

// Get header (first line of input) and remove quotes.
const header = lines[0].split(',').map(removeQuotes)

// The rest of the string is data. Split by comma and remove quotes.
const data = lines.splice(1).map(line => line.split(',').map(removeQuotes));

// Given header row and data row, combine into an object.
const zipWith = header => row => {
  return header.reduce((map, item, index) => {
    map[item] = row[index];
    return map;
  }, {});
}

// Now process all your data with a map :)
const result = data.map(zipWith(header));

console.log(result);
```

Pretty sure the output is exactly what you want:

```
[
  {
    "date": "03/29/2017",
    "initRegistrations": "0",
    "registrations": "0",
    "finalizeRegistrations": "0"
  },
  {
    "date": "03/30/2017",
    "initRegistrations": "5",
    "registrations": "4",
    "finalizeRegistrations": "4"
  },
  {
    "date": "03/31/2017",
    "initRegistrations": "42",
    "registrations": "0",
    "finalizeRegistrations": "0"
  },
  {
    "date": "04/01/2017",
    "initRegistrations": "192",
    "registrations": "0",
    "finalizeRegistrations": "0"
  },
  {
    "date": "04/02/2017",
    "initRegistrations": "4",
    "registrations": "0",
    "finalizeRegistrations": "0"
  },
  {
    "date": "04/03/2017",
    "initRegistrations": "23",
    "registrations": "0",
    "finalizeRegistrations": "0"
  },
  {
    "date": "04/04/2017",
    "initRegistrations": "5",
    "registrations": "0",
    "finalizeRegistrations": "0"
  }
]
```

Comment: awesome stuff @Triptych, fancy solution!

Comment: @Victor Thanks! This code is simpler to me at this point than the other answers. Functional programming is totally worth the investment =)

Answer (score 0):

You're probably looking for **split** which makes an array out of a string:

```
var a = s.split("\r\n");
```

This will give you an array of lines your string consists of. Then, if you need fields in each row, you can do a further **split** with another separator (comma?) in a for loop.

```
var tbl=[];
var rows = s.split("\r\n");
for(var y in rows) {
    var row = rows[y].split('"');
    tbl.push(row);
}
```

This will give you an array of arrays. With minimal effort you can improve it to recognize header row with field names, then use them as keys for each row. *(note: I'm on a mobile device right now so this is the best I can do for you but if you're still lost I can show you a more detailed example later.)*

Comment: hi @dkellner thanks for the help, that just build an array of strings. I think the perfect thing would be an object of objects, or an array of objects.

Comment: Voila, one step closer.